# Changed behavior in RegEx.Split after upgrade of .NET framework

Tags: regex, split

A client upgraded their systems and they started to report bugs in the output. Apparently, a string split before resulted in the following.

```
"a-b-c"   ->   {"a", "b", "c"}
```

Now, however, they get this.

```
"a-b-c"   ->   {"a", "-", "b", "-", "c"}
```

I've checked intellisense but as far I can tell, there's no option for turning on/off the inclusion of separators. How can one tackle this easily?

The best suggestion I have off the top of my head is to split using regex and then where it using link with the matching condition of regex. Seems redundant, though...

The current version is 4.5. Before, they had something **ooold**, like 2.0 or something.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Regex.Split("a-b-c", "-");

Comment: Very strange. That result would be expected for `Regex.Split("a-b-c", "(-)");`, but not for what you posted.

Comment: @TimPietzcker My bad. You're right, that's the pattern.   :)

Comment: Perhaps it's better to use Matches instead of SPlit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour of .NET 4.5 is correct.

The contents of capturing groups are added to the split result. Therefore, `Regex.Split("a-b-c", "(-)");` will add the dashes to the array.

Use `Regex.Split("a-b-c", "-");` instead.

Comment: Oh, it's correct, the behavior, all right. It's just different than before. I just found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) (see in the middle when they discuss the dates). Apparently, my client ran **ooooooooold** version of .NET before.